# @Retryable annotation not working for non Spring Bean class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am new to `spring-retry`. Basically, for retrying calls to REST APIs, I have integrated `spring-retry` into my spring-boot application. To do this, I have made following changes:

1. Added `spring-retry` to pom.xml.
2. Added following configuration:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableRetry
   public class RetryConfiguration {
   }
   ```
3. Finally added `@Retryable` annotation to the class (this class is not a Spring Bean) method that I would like to be retried for various exceptions as follows:

   ```
   public class OAuth1RestClient extends OAuthRestClient {

     @Override
     @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, value = {
        Exception.class},
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100, multiplier = 3))
     public Response executeRequest(OAuthRequest request)
         throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside Oauth1 client");
        return myService.execute(request);
     }
   ```

Now, the `executeRequest` method is not retrying. I am not able to understand if I am missing anything here.

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: If it isn't a spring bean this won;t work. AOP only (by default) works for Spring managed bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. So in that case, the only option remaining to me is using RetryTemplate I guess, in order to make the above method retry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class is not Spring managed (e.g. @Component/@Bean) the
annotation processor for `@Retryable` won't pick it up.

You can always manually define a `retryTemplate` and wrap calls with it:

```
RetryTemplate.builder()
        .maxAttempts(2)
        .exponentialBackoff(100, 10, 1000)
        .retryOn(RestClientException.class)
        .traversingCauses()
        .build();
```

and then

```
retryTemplate.execute(context -> myService.execute(request));
```

If you want to retry on multiple exception, this can happen via custom `RetryPolicy`

```
Map<Class(? extends Throwable), Boolean> exceptionsMap = new HashMap<>();
exceptionsMap.put(InternalServerError.class, true);
exceptionsMap.put(RestClientException.class, true);

SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, exceptionsMap, true); 
RetryTemplate.builder()
        .customPolicy(policy)
        .exponentialBackoff(100, 10, 1000)
        .build();
```

FYI: `RetryTemplate` is blocking and you might want to explore a non-blocking async retry approach like [async-retry](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry). - and the `retryOn()` supports a list of exceptions.

Comment: thanks. With RetryTemplate will I be able to retry for multiple exceptions say: RestClientException.class and InternalServerError.class ?

Comment: yes - see updated answer

Comment: Thanks. But with the retry template, I am still not able to retry the desired method on exceptions.  Let me post a question detailing the issue.