# RetryTemplate not working for Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am trying to add retry utility to a non-bean class method on multiple types of exceptions: `InternalServerError` and `BadGatewayErrorr`.

From taking the idea of my earlier post: [@Retryable annotation not working for non Spring Bean class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079418/retryable-annotation-not-working-for-non-spring-bean-class-method), I did the following:

1. Added `spring-retry` to `pom.xml`.
2. Added following configuration:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableRetry
   public class RetryConfiguration {
   }
   ```
3. Initialized and used `RetryTemplate` as follows:

   ```
   public abstract class OAuthRestClient {

       private RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate() {
            return RetryTemplate.builder()
                   .maxAttempts(2)
                   .exponentialBackoff(100, 2, 1000)
                   .retryOn(Exception.class)
                   .traversingCauses()
                   .build();
        }

        public Response call(Verb verb, String url, Object payload) {
           OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(verb, url);
           return execute(request);
        }

        private Response execute(OAuthRequest request) {
            Response response = null;
            try {
               response = getRetryTemplate().execute(context -> executeRequest(request));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               handleException(request,
                 BaseErrorCodes.REST_CLIENT_UNKNOWN_ERROR, ex);
            }
            return response;
        }

        public abstract Response executeRequest(OAuthRequest request) throws IOException;

     }

    public class OAuth1RestClient extends OAuthRestClient {

        @Override
        public Response executeRequest(OAuthRequest request) raised IOException {
           log.info("called ..");
           return myService.execute(request);
        }
    }
   ```

But, on exception, `executeRequest` is not getting retried, which should have happened as in `RetryTemplate` I have specified `retryOn` on `Exception.class` only.

I am not able to understand what I am missing here.

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need @EnableRetry if you are manually building the RetryTemplate. Can you make your implementation so that myService.execute(request); always throws a custom exception and try to retryOn that custom exception? Also keep in mind maxRetries includes the initial call, so you are effectively retrying once right now. Make sure log TRACE is enabled for the RetryTemplate. let us know the result after these changes. Try to log the context, which you are passing to the lambda, as well.

Comment: @hovanessyan, thanks. It seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @hovanessyan I have one doubt regarding using RetryTemplate. As of now, I can use it for retrying on exceptions but consider a scenario, where no exception came, but in response, we got 5xx error/4xx error codes. Can I use RetryTemplate for such a given set of error codes?

Comment: yes it is possible. I believe the default spring restTemplate will throw RestClientException in case any error happens during request/response communication (so you can include that in the retryOn list). But even if it doesn't you can always write custom logic to inspect the Http Status code of the response and wrap that in a custom exception, then add that exception to the retryOn list.